# Создание сервиса и bash-script

Tags: linux, bash

Помогите пожалуйста. Мне нужно создать сервис в Linux. Правильно ли я понимаю что нужно создать файл name.service ?

Мне нужно, чтобы этот сервис каждый день в определённое время запускал bash-скрипт. А в этом скрипте чтобы дата и время записывались в определённый лог-файл. Подскажите статьи или где почитать про это. Ну вообще дуб дубом. Не соображаю. Или посоветуйте книгу может, где понятно и подробно рассматривается линукс и как всё работает.

Comment: Это не совсем похоже на сервис, думаю вашу потребность в запуске в определенное время покроет и `cron`